# How to populate a parameter dynamically?

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I created a Pipeline with the assistant, that copy data from multiple tables on SQL Server on-premise into Azure Storage Account.
Each table is created into a parquet file.
But when a new table is created on-premise, I must change manually the JSON parameter in the Pipeline to integrate the new Table.

How to make this dynamically?

I know that the process is something like this:

1. Get the list of the tables on-premise
2. Store it into an Array in ADF
3. Use that Array in the ForEach component

But I can't figure it out how to do it.

Comment: Hey, Any reason why manually maintain the list? Which database are you using ? If it is SQL server, you can get the list of tables via Information_Schema.tables list

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Assuming you are using on Prem SQL server, you can have a lookup activity prior to For each activity and via Lookup activity, you can query Select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type='base table' to get the list of table names dynamically rather than manually maintaining a list of tables.